# How to use points and pixels on iphone?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, resolution, pixel, points

I know there is 960 x 640 screen resolution on iPhone4 and 480 x 320 on iPhone3 GS. Does that mean number of max pixels or number of points? I'm actually using points because I'm using functions like CGPointMake and I would like to know what is the max of points. But I'm a little bit confused about how many of them there are and how I should design my code when programming on iPhone3, iPhone4 and maybe above versions.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Those resolutions are in pixels. Almost all of the time, you should be dealing with points. iPhone screens are 320 x 480 points. The right thing happens on a retina display: CGPointMake(160, 240) will always be the center of the screen.

Comment: Just be wary about the status bar. If you account for that, the center of your "content view" is (160,220).

Comment: Fair enough — I’ve been most of my iPhone work with a full-screen game.